# Not able to check in excel using Apache POI if specific cell as per row and column is empty in Selenium with Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to write data in excel while running my tests and in Excel Test Class I have written a code to check if specific row under column is empty then write data else increment the row by 1 and then check same and write data.

**From another class I'm calling ExcelTest:**

```
ExcelTest sfName = new ExcelTest("C:\\Users\\abc\\eclipse-workspace\\dgc\\src\\com\\dg\\base\\utility\\TestData.xlsx");

sfName.setCellData("Sheet1","SingleFactor Campaign",SFCampName);
```

**ExcelTest Class**

```
public class ExcelTest
 {
public FileInputStream fis = null;
public FileOutputStream fos = null;
public XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
public XSSFSheet sheet = null;
public XSSFRow row = null;
public XSSFCell cell = null;
String xlFilePath;
boolean isEmptyStringCell;

public ExcelTest(String xlFilePath) throws Exception
{
    this.xlFilePath = xlFilePath;
    fis = new FileInputStream(xlFilePath);
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    fis.close();
}

public void setCellData(String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum, String value)
{
    try
    {
        int col_Num = -1;
        sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

        row = sheet.getRow(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) 
        {
            if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName))
            {
                col_Num = i;
            }
        }

        sheet.autoSizeColumn(col_Num);

        for(int j=2; j<7; j++)
            {
            row = sheet.getRow(j - 1);
            if(row==null)
                row = sheet.createRow(j - 1);

            cell = row.getCell(col_Num);

            isEmptyStringCell=cell.getStringCellValue().trim().isEmpty();

            if (this.isEmptyStringCell)
            {
                cell = row.createCell(col_Num);
                cell.setCellValue(value);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                j=j+1;
            }

            }

        /*row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
        if(row==null)
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum - 1);

        cell = row.getCell(col_Num);
        if(cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(col_Num);

        cell.setCellValue(value);*/

        System.out.println("The cell value is "+cell.getStringCellValue());

        fos = new FileOutputStream(xlFilePath);
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
   }
```

}

If we remove the block comment(mentioned above in code and add then comment to this code listed below then it will just write data in cell whichever is provided while calling the function.
In below code I'm starting a loop till max 7 rows and then checking if the cell contains data then increment or write data and once it writes then exit the loop.

```
          for(int j=2; j<7; j++)
            {
            row = sheet.getRow(j - 1);
            if(row==null)
                row = sheet.createRow(j - 1);

            cell = row.getCell(col_Num);

            isEmptyStringCell=cell.getStringCellValue().trim().isEmpty();

            if (this.isEmptyStringCell)
            {
                cell = row.createCell(col_Num);
                cell.setCellValue(value);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                j=j+1;
            }

        }
```

Expected: It should write data in a row which has no cell data.
Actual: It doesn't write anything.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Selenium. None of the code you posted references it so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution for the above question and only need to change few code and now it is working as expected:

```
          for(int j=2; j<7; j++)
            {
            row = sheet.getRow(j - 1);
            if(row==null)
                row = sheet.createRow(j - 1);

            cell = row.getCell(col_Num);
            //it will check if cell contains no value then create cell and set value                    
            if(cell == null)
            {
                cell = row.createCell(col_Num);
                cell.setCellValue(value);
                break;
            }

            }
```